# csla.net contrib - CslaContrib.MVC

Tags: csla

Has anyone got any experience/thoughts on the CSLA.netContrib project on codeplex - [here](http://cslacontrib.codeplex.com/).

In particular the CslaContrib.MVC part. Any pitfalls for the contrib? Anything where it caused any problems during development? etc. etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard of any issues but it would be worth asking about this on the [CSLA Forums](http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/8.aspx).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))